# Applying R commands (or an R script) on a RDD created by Java

Tags: java, r, apache-spark

I am currently using `Spark 2.4.0` in Java mode.

I have a chain of operations creates a Java `RDD` or a `Dataset`. Then at this step, it would be really convenient for me to continue these operations by applying on them some `R` commands or even a full `R` script, that seems to have more effectiveness for the work I have to do, for the next steps.

I've searched a lot, but it seems that programmers either choose `Java` or `R` language (with `SparkR`) when they use `Spark`, but don't use them all together. I wonder if its possible, and how.

In my mind, `RDD` being the same base class for `Java` and `R`, I should be able to do something like that :

```
sc.oneRfunction(myJavaRDD.rdd())
```

with the help of `Spark` that would have integrated all together...

But if it leads to a trap, going to something too complex (in terms of settings, especially), if `Spark` have not been planned for that use (mixing languages, in fact), warn me, please. Maybe I should avoid attempting this.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: It is not possible to mix language/tools like that, have to choose one or the other

Comment: In Python, there's `registerJavaFunction` you could use along with adding some `jar`s to your start-up config... I'm not seeing this function in the R API, however. Might have to do with the lack of `arrow` support in R ([for now](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/r))